# Android Studio - table layout sizes?

Tags: android, android-studio

New to Android Studio/java programming. I need to create a table with 3 cells that are the same size.

I've got something more or less working but am having problems with the sizing of the tables. How can I get the size of the cells all the same width. Ie each one a 1/3 of the screen?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.example.List">

 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:text="long string 1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:text="string 2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:text="s3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.List" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="9" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="long string 1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="string 2"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:text="s3"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the layout_width of the three TextView from wrap_content to match_parent, it will work because of their weight is set to '1'

Answer (score 0):

Change layout_width of the three TextView from "wrap_content" to "0dp" because of parent's(TableRow) orientation is horizontal.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to have done the job. However if the string is very long now and wraps the height of the box is different to the heights of the other boxes.

Comment: Then fix three layout_height like 100dp and add android:gravity=center :)